# undefined reference to vtable for Number

Tags: c++

I defined the print methods in Number class to circumvent errors, and I definitely declared const which those in need require, but it seems this program still throwing errors named vtable, and I know this is documented in some posts in stackoverflow, and I definitely read them, but couldn't find answer tailored to my case. Could you please help me?

[image]

NumberMain.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Number.h"
#include "Fraction.h"
#include "Complex.h"

using namespace std;

Complex * makeComplex() {
    Complex * complex1 = new Complex;
    float real, imag;

    cout << "What is the Real Part? ";
    cin >> real;
    cout << "What is the Imaginary Part? ";
    cin >> imag;
    complex1->setReal(real);
    complex1->setImaginary(imag);
    return complex1;
}

Fraction * makeFraction() {
    Fraction * frac1 = new Fraction;
    int numer, denom;

    cout << "What is the Numerator? ";
    cin >> numer;
    cout << "What is the Denominator? ";
    cin >> denom;
    frac1->setNumerator(numer).setDenominator(denom).simplify();
    return frac1;
}

int main() {
    Number * num1;
    int numberType;

    cout << "1) Complex or 2) Fraction ";
    cin >> numberType;

    switch(numberType) {
        case 1 : num1 = makeComplex(); break;
        case 2 : num1 = makeFraction(); break;
        default : cout << "Error: Invalid Number Class" << endl; return 1;
    }

    num1->print();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Number.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Number {
    public:
        virtual void print() const;
};

void Number::print() const {}
```

Fraction.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Number.h"

using namespace std;

class Fraction : public Number {
    private:
        int numerator, denominator;
    public:
        Fraction();
        Fraction(int newNumer);
        Fraction(int newNumer, int newDenom);
        void print() const;
        void setNumerAndDenom(int newNumer, int newDenom);
        Fraction & setNumerator(int newNumer);
        Fraction & setDenominator(int newDenom);
        int getNumerator() const;
        int getDenominator() const;
        void simplify();
        Fraction operator+(Fraction frac2);
        Fraction operator-(Fraction frac2);
        Fraction operator*(Fraction frac2);
        Fraction operator/(Fraction frac2);
        bool operator==(Fraction frac2);
        bool operator>(Fraction frac2);
        bool operator<(Fraction frac2);
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, Fraction & frac1);
int GreatestCommonDenominator(int num1, int num2);
```

Complex.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Number.h"

using namespace std;

class Complex : public Number {
    private:
        float real = 0;
        float imag = 0;
    public:
        Complex();
        Complex(float newReal);
        Complex(float newReal, float newImag);
        void print() const;
        void setRealAndImaginary(float newReal, float newImag);
        void setReal(float newReal);
        void setImaginary(float newImag);
        float getReal() const;
        float getImaginary() const;
        Complex operator+(Complex complex2);
        Complex operator-(Complex complex2);
        Complex operator*(Complex complex2);
        Complex operator/(Complex complex2);
        bool operator==(Complex complex2);
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, Complex & complex1);
```

Complex.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.h"

using namespace std;

Complex::Complex() {
    real = 0;
    imag = 0;
}

Complex::Complex(float newReal) {
    real = newReal;
    imag = 0;
}

Complex::Complex(float newReal, float newImag) {
    real = newReal;
    imag = newImag;
}

void Complex::print() const {
    cout << real << " + j(" << imag << ")" << endl << endl;
}

void Complex::setRealAndImaginary(float newReal, float newImag) {
    real = newReal;
    imag = newImag;
}

void Complex::setReal(float newReal) {
    real = newReal;
}

void Complex::setImaginary(float newImag) {
    imag = newImag;
}

float Complex::getReal() const {
    return real;
}

float Complex::getImaginary() const {
    return imag;
}

Complex Complex::operator+(Complex complex2) {
    Complex newComplex;
    float newReal = real + complex2.getReal();
    float newImag = imag + complex2.getImaginary();
    newComplex.setRealAndImaginary(newReal, newImag);

    return newComplex;
}

Complex Complex::operator-(Complex complex2) {
    Complex newComplex;
    float newReal = real - complex2.getReal();
    float newImag = imag - complex2.getImaginary();
    newComplex.setRealAndImaginary(newReal, newImag);

    return newComplex;
}

Complex Complex::operator*(Complex complex2) {
    Complex newComplex;
    float newReal = real*complex2.getReal() - imag*complex2.getImaginary();
    float newImag = imag*complex2.getReal() + real*complex2.getImaginary();
    newComplex.setRealAndImaginary(newReal, newImag);

    return newComplex;
}

Complex Complex::operator/(Complex complex2) {
    Complex newComplex;
    float newReal = (real*complex2.getReal() + imag*complex2.getImaginary()) / (complex2.getReal()*complex2.getReal() + complex2.getImaginary()*complex2.getImaginary());
    float newImag = (imag*complex2.getReal() - real*complex2.getImaginary()) / (complex2.getReal()*complex2.getReal() + complex2.getImaginary()*complex2.getImaginary());
    newComplex.setRealAndImaginary(newReal, newImag);

    return newComplex;
}

bool Complex::operator==(Complex complex2) {
    return (real == complex2.getReal() && imag == complex2.getImaginary());
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, Complex & complex1) {
    output << complex1.getReal() << " + j(" << complex1.getImaginary() << ")";
    return output;
}
```

Fraction.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Fraction.h"

using namespace std;

Fraction::Fraction() {
    setNumerAndDenom(0, 1);
}

Fraction::Fraction(int newNumer) {
    setNumerAndDenom(newNumer, 1);
}

Fraction::Fraction(int newNumer, int newDenom) {
    setNumerAndDenom(newNumer, newDenom);
}

void Fraction::print() const {
    cout << numerator << "/" << denominator;
}

void Fraction::setNumerAndDenom(int newNumer, int newDenom) {
    if (newDenom == 0) {
        cout << "Error creating a fraction with a zero denominator" << endl;
        return;
    }
    numerator = newNumer;
    denominator = newDenom;
    simplify();
}

Fraction & Fraction::setNumerator(int newNumer) {
   numerator = newNumer;
   return (*this);
}

Fraction & Fraction::setDenominator(int newDenom) {
    denominator = newDenom;
    return (*this);
}

int Fraction::getNumerator() const {
    return numerator;
}

int Fraction::getDenominator() const {
    return denominator;
}

void Fraction::simplify() {
    int gcd = GreatestCommonDenominator(numerator, denominator);

    numerator /= gcd;
    denominator /= gcd;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+(Fraction frac2) {
    Fraction newFraction;
    int newDenom = denominator * frac2.getDenominator();
    int newNumer = numerator * frac2.getDenominator() + frac2.getNumerator() * denominator;
    newFraction.setNumerAndDenom(newNumer, newDenom);

    return newFraction;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator-(Fraction frac2) {
    Fraction newFraction;
    int newDenom = denominator * frac2.getDenominator();
    int newNumer = numerator * frac2.getDenominator() - frac2.getNumerator() * denominator;
    newFraction.setNumerAndDenom(newNumer, newDenom);

    return newFraction;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator*(Fraction frac2) {
    Fraction newFraction;
    int newDenom = denominator * frac2.getDenominator();
    int newNumer = numerator * frac2.getNumerator();
    newFraction.setNumerAndDenom(newNumer, newDenom);

    return newFraction;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator/(Fraction frac2) {
    Fraction newFraction;
    int newDenom = denominator * frac2.getNumerator();
    int newNumer = numerator * frac2.getDenominator();
    newFraction.setNumerAndDenom(newNumer, newDenom);

    return newFraction;
}

bool Fraction::operator==(Fraction frac2) {
    return (numerator * frac2.getDenominator() == denominator * frac2.getNumerator());
}

bool Fraction::operator>(Fraction frac2) {
    return (numerator * frac2.getDenominator() > denominator * frac2.getNumerator());
}

bool Fraction::operator<(Fraction frac2) {
    return (numerator * frac2.getDenominator() < denominator * frac2.getNumerator());
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, Fraction & frac) {
    output << frac.getNumerator() << "/" << frac.getDenominator();
    return output;
}

int GreatestCommonDenominator(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 == 0) return num2;
    if (num1 < 0) return GreatestCommonDenominator(-num1, num2);
    if (num1 > num2) return GreatestCommonDenominator(num2, num1);
    return GreatestCommonDenominator(num2-num1, num1);
}
```

Comment: The error message mentions `Complex.cpp`, which you haven't shown. How does it fit into the picture?

Comment: Could you also provide code for Fraction.h and Complex.h? And their .cpp (if any)?

Comment: Sorry for making lack of information, and I also provided Complex and Fraction bundle codes.

Comment: Please don't change the original question. If you need to add something, add it, but don't remove the most relevant part of the original (the actual error you were getting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define `Number::print()` like that in the header file. It needs to be either marked inline, be in the class declaration itself, or in a separate cpp file.

```
class Number {
    public:
        virtual void print() const;
        virtual inline void print2() const;
        virtual void print3() const {} // OK
};

void Number::print() const {}  // not OK, linker error(s)
inline void Number::print2() const {}  // OK (the "inline" here is optional)
```

Comment: Hello, but I'm getting warnings in NumberMain.cpp and Complex.cpp that non-static data member initializers only available with std=c++11

Comment: @DanielMaguire Different error, different question. But it's referring to `class Complex ... { private: float real = 0; float imag = 0;` part. This is indeed C++11 (and up) only. Do you have C++11 enabled? This would be a compiler/build system setting.